# Lenovo Yoga 2 wifi 'disabled by hardware switch', no wifi hardware switch, tried installing both 15.10 and 16.04

Tags: system-installation, 16.04, 15.10

I keep trying to install Ubuntu on my Lenovo Yoga 2, however, my wifi card must have some issues running Ubuntu since a new update (?) When I tried installing 16.04, it didn't say anything but wifi just wouldn't connect, and when I tried installing 15.10 it said that my wifi hardware switch was turned off. I really want/need to get out of the Windows trap, I don't have much technical know-how besides basic command line commands, but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In terminal, type "sudo rfkill list" and copy/paste the results here. And you're sure that you don't have a wireless hardware disable switch on the side/front edges of your computer?

Comment: 2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop temporarily enables my wifi, allowing me to use Ubuntu... however, it's kinda annoying entering that command in every time, and it doesn't always work right away- sometimes I have to log out, and log back in to get my wifi working. I my laptop had an ethernet port, I'd just use that. Sorry for the late reply, I sorta got frustrated and gave up lol

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. Accepting the answer is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add `blacklist ideapad-laptop`.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Phew, I was getting tired of Windows' sluggishness, I thought I'd have to stick with that.